# Order menu bar drop down on ASP.NET web page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menubar

I have a menu bar on my ASP.NET page and some of the content in the Menu bar has drop downs with more results. When I hover over some of the content in the menu bar which shows a drop down, the drop down is ordered to be behind everything on the page, meaning I cannot see what content is being shown.

Here is an example:

[image]

Is there a way I can get the menu bar to appear above the other information?

Comment: Increase z-index value for dropdown

Comment: Have you tried z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u could use **z-index** in menu css file

```
z-index:999;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer worked perfectly. Quick question, is it the higher the number to higher the priority?